# Display value instead of title in pie chart

Tags: android, androidplot

I am developing an application which uses `androidplot`. I need to display the value of the segments in pie chart instead of the title. How can I do it

```
pie2 = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.PieChart2);
pie2.getPie().setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

s1 = new Segment("s1", 3);
s2 = new Segment("s2", 7);
s3 = new Segment("s3", 9);
s4 = new Segment("s4", 9);

pie2.addSegment(s1, sf2);
pie2.addSegment(s2, sf4);
pie2.addSegment(s3, sf1);
pie2.addSegment(s4, sf3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is use the value as title in the Segment constructor.

```
s1 = new Segment("3", 3);
```

If you want to keep the references to your Segments , you can override the class to add another field e.g. Tag:

```
public class MySegment extends Segment {
    private String tag;

    public MySegment(String tag, String title, Number value) {
        super(title, value);
        setTag(tag);
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate segment like this:

```
MySegment s1 = new MySegment("s1","3",3);
```

Hope this works for you :)